# Why doesn't this method of deleting files inside a folder work?

Tags: c++, winapi, directory, delete-file

```
std::wstring inxmpath ( L"folder" );
HANDLE hFind;
BOOL bContinue = TRUE;
WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
hFind = FindFirstFile(inxmpath.c_str(), &data); 
// If we have no error, loop through the files in this dir
int counter = 0;
while (hFind && bContinue) {
        std::wstring filename(data.cFileName);
        std::string fullpath = "folder/";
        fullpath += (const char* )filename.c_str();
        if(remove(fullpath.c_str())!=0) return error;
    bContinue = FindNextFile(hFind, &data);
    counter++;
}
FindClose(hFind); // Free the dir
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work, I think it has something to do with the conversions between wstring and string however I'm not sure about that. I have a folder which has some .txt files, I need to delete all of them using C++. There are no folders in it nothing. How hard can this be?

Comment: Have you tried setting `inxmpath` to an absolute folder path?

Comment: the .exe and the 'folder' are in the same folder. I'm not sure if I need to do this if that's the case.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not helpful. What are you observing vs. what you expected, and what have you already tried to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Secondly, according to MSDN about the `FindFirstFile` function:

"Searches a directory for a file or subdirectory with a name that 
matches a specific name (or partial name if wildcards are used)."

I cannot see a wildcard in your input string, so I can only guess that `FindFirstFile` will look for files named `"folder"` in the current execution directory.

Try looking for `"folder\\*"`.

Comment: I'll add that `FindFirstFile` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` on error instead of 0 like the OP is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

2 problems I can see:

1) I'd stick to wide-strings only, if that's what you need. Try calling [DeleteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead (assuming your project is UNICODE), which you can pass a wide-string.

2) You are using relative paths, where an absolute one would be more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
std::wstring inxmpath = L"c:\\path to\\folder\\"; 
std::wstring fullpath = inxmpath + L"*.*";

WIN32_FIND_DATA data; 
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileW(fullpath.c_str(), &data);  
if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    // If we have no error, loop through the files in this dir 
    BOOL bContinue = TRUE; 
    int counter = 0; 
    do
    { 
        if ((data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == 0)
        {
            fullpath = inxmpath + data.cFileName; 
            if (!DeleteFileW(fullpath.c_str()))
            {
                FindClose(hFind);
                return error; 
            }
            ++counter; 
            bContinue = FindNextFile(hFind, &data); 
        }
    }
    while (bContinue);
    FindClose(hFind); // Free the dir 
}
```